# How to enable TUN in Ubuntu running in a docker container

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, openvpn, wireguard

So basically I'm running an Ubuntu container in docker, with the host system running Ubuntu Server 20.4 LTS, and the container running 22.4 LTS. My intended goal is to have a container to download torrents over a VPN in a container. Now I do not need to be able to access the torrents over web, so no access to my local network is needed. My problem is that anyway I install OpenVpn, WireGuard, or other VPN software, it is unable to connect or load due to a missing "TUN" module. I have already tried a whole plethora of text and YouTube tutorials with no avail. I already have WireGuard and OpenVPN installed, along with Linux headers on the host system, and Linux headers on the container. I have tried using Alpine and Ubuntu and the problem is a thing on both. If you could help solve this problem I will be eternally grateful. Thanks in advance, Duncan.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys... It turns out to access the TUN module the container needs to be run in "privileged mode".